# difference between TRC andDRC architecture?

Tags: database, architecture

How Tuple Relaional Calculas and Domain Relational Calculas works in Database.What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very big conceptual difference between the two.In case of tuple relational calculus ,you operate on each tuples but in case of domain relational calculus ,you deal with each column or attribute.Both methods can be used to get any result.

The tuple-oriented calculus uses a tuple variables i.e., variable whose only permitted values are tuples of that relation. E.g. QUELThe domain-oriented calculus has domain variables i.e., variables that range over the underlying domains instead of over relation. E.g. ILL, DEDUCE....The tuple-oriented calculus uses a tuple variables i.e., variable whose only permitted values are tuples of that relation. E

Answer (score 0):

Basically,TRC is stands for the tuple relation calculus and DRC is stands for the domain relation calculus.Tuple contains the single row of the table where as domain contains the atomic values.

Comment: Could you add a little more description about the explanation you provide?